# get raw content (String format) of MSG Outlook file in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, msg

I'm trying to read the raw content of a .MSG Outlook File in a Java application.

I tried to use Apache POI HSMF, it works well to extract some fields but I would need to get the exact raw file content. As far as I can see Apache POI is not providing such functionality.

On the other hand If I'm trying to open the .MSG file (binary format I think) I'm not able to write it into a String format.

Do you have any idea how I can read such msg file and copy its content into a String ?

Comment: What do you mean by "raw file content"? The rich text part of the email? Plain text? Attachment? Other?

Comment: everything....the header and the different parts (HTML Body, Text body) with the different boundaries

Comment: If you need *everything*, then just use the raw bytes of the MSG file, that contains everything! Otherwise, you need to fetch individual parts one-by-one, the MSG file format doesn't store email in mime-like plain text, only parts

Comment: ok, understood. But how can I read the raw bytes in String format then ?

Comment: Base64 encode them? That'll let you hold the raw message as a string. However, what I think you want isn't in the file format, as MSG doesn't work how you seem to suggest it might...

Comment: yes...I've seen it....anyway I'll find another way...

Comment: The msg file format (a specific version of the Microsoft compound binary file format) includes a bunch of binary metadata (a header, an entire directory structure, and “files” in the directory structure for each field). Some fields are text, some are binary. The binary ones cannot, in general, be converted to Strings. Can you be more clear on what you are trying to retrieve? Message body and header are easy, other data may be harder to extract.

Comment: James, at least, I wanted to extract body header and attachments....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache POI HSMF includes the tools you need to extract the body, header, and attachments, as you requested in your comment. In fact, the HSMF test application [org.apache.poi.hsmf.extractor.OutlookTextExtractor](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/REL_4_1_2/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hsmf/extractor/OutlookTextExtractor.java) gets you To, From, Subject, and Body. It even includes code which goes through the headers and the attachments, you would only need to modify it to show the complete headers and to write the attachment content to a new file.

To run it, download the following jar files:

- poi-scratchpad-4.1.2.jar
- poi-4.1.2.jar
- commons-math3-3.6.1.jar

And run (on Windows) via

```
java -cp "poi-scratchpad-4.1.2.jar;poi-4.1.2.jar;commons-math3-3.6.1.jar"  org.apache.poi.hsmf.extractor.OutlookTextExtractor msg-file
```

On Linux, change the path separator in the classpath to “;”